# Why RPATH_CHECK in CMake deletes executable?

Tags: cmake, qt6

The following CMake's action will delete executable if RPATH is not the same.

```
file(RPATH_CHECK
    FILE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/moc"
    RPATH "\$ORIGIN/../lib")
```

If RPATH will not be `$ORIGIN/../lib` then - ops, and no more executable.

Is it correct behavior of CMake, or it is a bug?

What `RPATH_CHECK` should do?

I caught this problem in Qt 6.2.1 on Linux. Qt builds successfully, but `cmake --install .` fails because CMake deletes executable in reason of `RPATH_CHECK` file's action with mismatched RPATH (declared and actual). Actual RPATH is `::::::::::::::` at point of execution `RPATH_CHECK`.

I'm on Kubuntu 20.04. I installed sources of Qt with official Online Installer. To configure Qt I used:

```
./configure -nomake tests -nomake examples -skip qttest -skip qtwebengine -skip qtwebview -skip qtpositioning -skip qtsensors -skip qtserialbus -skip qtserialport -skip qtnfc -skip qtcharts -skip qt3d -skip qtwayland -skip qtcoap -skip qtdatavis3d -skip qtlottie -skip qtmqtt -skip qtnetworkauth -skip qtopcua -skip qtquick3d -skip qtquicktimeline -skip qtremoteobjects -skip qtvirtualkeyboard -skip qtwebchannel -skip qtwebsockets -release -shared -skip qt5compat -skip qtdoc -skip qtscxml -skip qttranslations -skip qttools
```

Then

```
cmake --build . --parallel
```

CMake version 3.16.3

Comment: I cannot find your recent question about the very similar problem, it seems that you have deleted it. Please note, that when you find more information about the problem described in a question post, on Stack Overflow *preferred* way is to **edit** the question post, other than deleting existing question post and creating a new one.

Comment: `RPATH_CHECK` is **internal** CMake feature. It is not described in the documentation and it is not intended to be used in any code except the one generated by CMake itself. Asking about what an internal feature could do has a little sense: only CMake developers could answer, and they unlikely wish to answer because they won't an internal feature to be used in the outer code. Instead, ask about the **specific problem** of your CMake project. As far as I remember, your previous question was more about the specific project.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Sure, but that question was very spatial, there were a lot of delusions, and no one comment or answer, so I decided to create a clear question. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I know that `RPATH_CHECK` is internal feature, but CMake generates its own install script with such things, and fails. I investigated that the problem of mismatched RPATH, and just trying to understand which this issue: CMake's or Qt's project.

Comment: "just trying to understand which this issue: CMake's or Qt's project" - As usual: Assume the error to be in your project. Unless you could show the project and everyone could find that the project is correct.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I pointed in question to the project with just a few words, without mess. So this question became very clear in my opinion.

Comment: You don't think that you are the only person who builds and installs QT from sources on Linux, do you? This doesn't mean that QT is without flaws, but probably these flaws could be triggered only in a specific condition. On which Linux distro you are installing QT? Have you passed any specific parameters when configure QT (`cmake` call)? What CMake version do you use? Pretend you are filling a bugreport for QT developers and want they to be able to **reproduce** your problem: what information could be useful for it? Please, update the question post with **more details** about your situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why RPATH_CHECK in CMake deletes executable?

Because that's what it does. (?)

> Is it correct behavior of CMake, or it is a bug?

Correct.

> What RPATH_CHECK should do?

Check if the file has desired RPATH, and if it doesn't, the file should be removed.

If you have any other concerns about RPATH features in CMake, I posted the source code in the last answer - all is there. Search for `RPATH_CHECK` in CMake source tree, and you'll find the find the function - from function names you can "guess" meaning and the algorithm used.